# SQL query for calculating a monthly total out of a running total

Tags: mysql

I have a table titled "Reports" in MySQL that has a column titled "Flow_Total" which has a running total value that goes up every day and never resets, what i need is a query that takes the values that are stored in the "Flow_Total" column and divide them by month and tells me how much the value goes up every month.

This is how i would like to see the data:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=BC22A6E2F92CE833!11843&authkey=!ACgipFLKDJTBlN8

The value for the month is written on the last day of that month.
A summary of what i want to do is subtract the monthly change from the Flow_Total and display it in a separate column titled Monthly Total.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You'll need to at least add some sample data, a table layout and a desired result. Is there data for every day or just month starts or ends? Is the `Total Flow` column in your image the value at the start or end of the month? Please clarify, and tell us what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, i have been searching the web this past week and haven't found anything remotely promising. And the Total flow column is recorded at the end of every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most pleasing SQL to the eyes, but this should do what you're asking; it'll just self join the table with itself delayed 1 month and calculate the difference from that.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(a.`DATE`), '%b-%y') `DATE`,
       MAX(a.`FLOW_TOTAL`) `Flow Total`,
       (MAX(a.`FLOW_TOTAL`) - MAX(b.`FLOW_TOTAL`)) `Monthly Total`
FROM Reports a
LEFT JOIN Reports b
  ON YEAR(a.`DATE`)  =  YEAR(DATE_ADD(b.`DATE`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND
     MONTH(a.`DATE`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(b.`DATE`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
GROUP BY YEAR(a.`DATE`), MONTH(a.`DATE`)
ORDER BY a.`DATE` DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09234/2).